# How to escape node names in knife

Tags: chef-infra, knife

I have a node name that begins with `--` and I'm not able to do anything with it in `knife` (ie. `knife node show --mynode` returns the help documentation viewing `--mynode` as an invalid `option`).

I've tried with double and single quotes with no luck. Is there a way to escape the node name so knife can parse the argument as the node name and not try to parse it as an option?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest option is to use `knife raw`:

```
$ knife raw /nodes/--mynode
$ knife raw -m DELETE /nodes/--mynode
```

You can also probably use `knife node show -- --mynode` but I haven't tried that in a while.

Comment: Actually just using `knife node delete -- --mynode` did the trick!

Comment: That trick works in just about any program that follows Unix command line parsing rules :-) Also helpful when you end up with a file named `-rf`